# TLS mutual authentication return error as combination of host and port requires TLS

Tags: go

I am trying to have a TLS mutual auth setup but I am getting error from server as `This combination of host and port requires TLS.`

Below is the code I am trying to use.

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httputil" //"os"
    "time"
)

//HTTPClient will retrun an HTTP client back to user
type HTTPClient struct {
    *http.Client
}

//NewClient will return an HTTP client with TLS mutual Auth set
//Input: isSecure
//Return: HTTPClient
func NewClient() *HTTPClient {
    log.Println("Setting up TLS configuration")
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("cert.pem", "key.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to read certificates ", err)
    }
    //load CA certificate
    caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("ca.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to read CA certificate ", err)
    }
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert)

    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        RootCAs:            caCertPool,              //RootCAs
        MinVersion:         tls.VersionTLS12,        //Support only TLS 1.2 or higher
        Certificates:       []tls.Certificate{cert}, //Reject any TLS certificate that cannot be validated
        InsecureSkipVerify: false,                   //Make sure we alway verify certificate
    }
    tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()
    transport := &http.Transport{
        TLSClientConfig: tlsConfig,
        DialTLS: (&net.Dialer{
            Timeout: 30 * time.Second,
        }).Dial,
        TLSHandshakeTimeout: 30 * time.Second,
        MaxIdleConns:        10,
    }
    return &HTTPClient{
        Client: &http.Client{
            Transport: transport,
            Timeout:   time.Second * 10,
        },
    }
}

func main() {
    url := "https://35.184.226.101:443/test"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error while creating request for ", url)
        return
    }
    resp, err := NewClient().Do(req)
    response, err := httputil.DumpResponse(resp, true)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Error while dumping Request ", err)
    }
    log.Println(string(response))
    /* Output
        018/12/03 19:19:38 Setting up TLS configuration
    2018/12/03 19:19:38 HTTP/1.1 400
    Connection: close
    Content-Type: text/plain;charset=ISO-8859-1

    Bad Request
    This combination of host and port requires TLS.
    */

}
```

Any thought where is the issue. Also how I can enable extra tracing so that we can get more information.

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong here, since you are getting a response. You have to inspect the server code to figure out why you are getting this response.

Comment: It looks like you might be ignoring potential errors. Is the error nil after `NewClient().Do(req)`?

Comment: @MadWombat I tried even checking error after making Do request. But no error is being reported.